# Taxonomy with s search variable not working together

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type

```
<?php 
       $query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'books',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $_POST['paged'],
                    'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'history_new',
                        'terms' =>$hist, 
                        ),
                        array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'history_old',
                        'terms' =>$hisold,
                        )
                    ),
                's' => $searchResource,
                'exact' => true,
        ));
?>
```

**I want to search posts with 2 taxonomy or text that is in s variable. It works fine with both taxonomies but not working when i search using text box, Like i have two select fields for 2 taxonomies and one text input with submit button**